# ID of unknown can in shed

Tags: repair

It is in a shed I am helping to clean out.
When I know what it is, then I can pass on or dispose properly. I suspect some sort of anti rust or paint for metalwork.

Location :Australia.

The company is long gone, so a google search is not helpful.

[image]

Comment: Given the partial text, I wonder if it's blue layout dye (use to coat metal and then scratch layout lines into the coating, leaving the layout lines as bare metal.) A staple of old-school metalworking.

Comment: Owner had been a high school teacher, and did everything around the home himself.

Comment: On a related line, E2694 pulls up a standard for testing for ATP in "water miscible metalworking fluids" (cutting fluids that are mixtures of water and oil, rather than cutting oils.)

Comment: BTW: I'm pretty sure that "Oxy" is one of the tradenames for the Occidental Chemical Co, which is still a going concern, albeit not really a consumer-facing one (the logo matches a logo I've seen them use in other places)

Comment: There are 19 results at the USPTO trademark search for the company name (seems to be worldwide, with an Austrailian division), most recently in 1973, but none of the trademarked names start BLUD... They also made plating solutions, I gather, which can be a nasty disposal prospect.

Comment: Come on @ecnerwal I still use Dykem today steel blue layout fluid, old school, what an insult + answers should go down below.

Comment: No insult, I know because I've used it myself - but modern CNC mill boys don't use a lot of layout dye. And they might be a bit lost in the shops I learned in. And nothing here has risen beyond the point of speculation to be an actual answer.